# Python: Adding an item a list which is a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I can't figure out how to add certain values to a list for each individual key. I have a few types (b,m,t,d,c) which are the keys, and then I want to add costs of those items to a list that is the value of the dictionary each time I go through the loop.
This is what I have so far:

```
a={}
allitemcostb=[]
allitemcostm=[]
allitemcostt=[]
allitemcostd=[]
allitemcostc=[]
n=4

while n>0:
    itemtype=raw_input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")
    itemcost=input("enter the item cost:")
    if itemtype="b":    
        allitemcostb.append(itemcost)
        a[itemtype]=allitemcostb
    if itemtype="m":
        allitemcostm.append(itemcost)
        a[itemtype]=allitemcostm
    if itemtype="t":
        allitemcostt.append(itemcost)
        a[itemtype]=allitemcostt
    if itemtype="d":
        allitemcostd.append(itemcost)
        a[itemtype]=allitemcostd
    if itemtype="c":
        allitemcostc.append(itemcost)
        a[itemtype]=allitemcostc
    else:
        print "Sorry please enter a valid type"
    n=n-1
print a
```

It keeps giving me error messages, whether it be something isn't defined, or improper syntax.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know about pythons, but have you seen this already? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `a[itemtype] = allitemcostb`, which simply sets that key's value to a new cost, you need to create a `list` if that key doesn't exist yet or add it to the existing `list` if it does. Do this with the `setdefault()` method.

The following uses just a dictionary with `itemtype:[itemcost, itemcost...]` and no separate `list`s, dispenses with the manually-incremented `while` loop in favor of a `for` loop with an `xrange`, and replaces the large branching structure with a more direct structure (instead of "if it's `a`, do `a`," it does "do whatever it is"). The line `if itemtype in ('b', 'm', 't', 'd', 'c'):` checks that the entered `itemtype` is a single-character string representing an available option. If the entered `itemcost` can't be converted to a `float`, the error is caught and the user is prompted to try again.

```
a={}
n=4

for i in xrange(n):
    itemtype = raw_input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")
    itemcost = raw_input("enter the item cost:")
    try:
        itemcost = float(itemcost)
    except ValueError:
        print "Sorry, please enter a valid cost."
        break
    if itemtype in ('b', 'm', 't', 'd', 'c'):
        a.setdefault(itemtype, []).append(itemcost)
    else:
        print "Sorry, please enter a valid type."

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = {}
all_item_cost_b=[]
all_item_cost_m=[]
all_item_cost_t=[]
all_item_cost_d=[]
all_item_cost_c=[]
n = 4

while n > 0:
    item_type = input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")
    item_cost = input("enter the item cost:")
    if item_type == "b":
        all_item_cost_b.append(item_cost)
        a[item_type] = all_item_cost_b
    elif item_type == "m":
        all_item_cost_m.append(item_cost)
        a[item_type] = all_item_cost_m
    elif item_type == "t":
        all_item_cost_t.append(item_cost)
        a[item_type] = all_item_cost_t
    elif item_type == "d":
        all_item_cost_d.append(item_cost)
        a[item_type] = all_item_cost_d
    elif item_type == "c":
        all_item_cost_c.append(item_cost)
        a[item_type] = all_item_cost_c
    else:
        print("Sorry please enter a valid type")
    n = n - 1
print(a)
```

Give us a feedback. Don't forget to mark as answered, if this solves your problem.
Cheers.

Comment: I guess @TigerHawkT3 has a more professional and tidy response.

Comment: Changing the assignments to equality checks is a good change, but there is no other improvement to the code's algorithm, results, or readability. Also, the `raw_` in `raw_input()` was there for a reason - the OP is using Python 2, so your line of `item_type = input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")` will result in a new error for the OP.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: "Also, the `raw_` in `raw_input()` was there for a reason..." I suspected so too, because once I pasted his code on my editor, that gave me an error. I am actually using python 3.5 and never had a taste of older versions. Thanks for that, and sorry OP for doing more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions.

The fist one  is not so strict. it will allow the user to enter any value for the itemtype but not for the itemcost

```
a={}
n=4

while (n>0):
    itemtype = input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")
    itemcost = input("enter the item cost:")

    while(True):
        try:
            itemcost = float(itemcost)
            break;
        except ValueError:
            print ("Sorry, please enter a valid cost.")
            itemcost = input("enter the item cost:")

    if itemtype.lower() in "b m t d c".split():
        a[itemtype] = a.get(itemtype,list())+[itemcost]

    n-=1

print (a)
```

This second form will be strict for both user inputs and will keep prompting till the user enters the expected value

```
a={}
n=4

while (n>0):
    itemtype = input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")
    ##user enters a wrong value
    while(itemtype.lower() not in "b m t d c".split() ):
        print ("Sorry, please enter a valid item.")
        itemtype = input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")

    itemcost = input("enter the item cost:")
    ##user enters a wrong value
    while(True):
        try:
            itemcost = float(itemcost)
            break;
        except ValueError:
            print ("Sorry, please enter a valid cost.")
            itemcost = input("enter the item cost:")

    a[itemtype] = a.get(itemtype,list())+[itemcost]

    n-=1

print (a)
```

Comment: if the `input("enter the item type-b,m,t,d,c:")` command does not work for you change it to `raw_input(" ")`. The command doesn't work for me